# Insert instead of update with Spring Data JPA

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have a simple model. Entity A has one-to-many relation with entity B. They are linked using an association table. My use case is fetching/inserting/updating entity in simple web application:

1. Fetch entity A as JSON.
2. Put entity A (even unchanged) to save.
3. Constraint violation: hibernate tries to insert already existing row into association table.

Why is this happening? Hibernate has everything what is needed to determine if merge or persist should be done on parent and its children. Why it doesn't check if the children are already linked with the parent?

Parent.java:

```
package com.example;

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Version;

import lombok.EqualsAndHashCode;

@Entity
@EqualsAndHashCode(exclude = { "id" })
public class Parent {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private Set<Child> children = new HashSet<>();

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Set<Child> getChildren() {
        return children;
    }

    public void setChildren(Set<Child> children) {
        this.children = children;
    }

}
```

Child.java

```
package com.example;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Version;

import lombok.EqualsAndHashCode;

@Entity
@EqualsAndHashCode(exclude = { "id" })
public class Child {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    private Long value;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Long getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(Long value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

}
```

ParentService.java:

```
package com.example;

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

    @Service
    public class ParentService {

        @Autowired
        private ParentRepository parentRepository;

        @Transactional
        public Parent save(Parent parent) {
            return parentRepository.save(parent);
        }

    }
```

ParentRepository.java:

```
package com.example;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface ParentRepository extends JpaRepository<Parent, Long>{

}
```

What is interesting when I add @Version properties then everything works, but I cannot find explanation why. The other solution is to fetch oldParent by id, just for the sake of fetching - then it also works, even without @Version, but when I will get oldParent children and initialize it using size() then again, undesired inserts are coming. Why those things even work? It is something related to Hibernate or Spring Data JPA repositories?

Comment: Did you implement `equals` and `hashCode` on `B`?

Comment: Can you provide some java code?

Comment: @AliDehgani yes, I did

Comment: Then provide some java code

Comment: What happened to those versions?

Comment: @AliDehgani using versions everything works but still I do not know why, because they are not necessary to conclude whether merge or persist should be done on the children, that's why I removed them from the snippets.

Comment: Are you constructing the `Parent` argument by yourself (without id)?

Comment: @AliDehgani No, the Parent argument is passed to ParentService from ParentController, after marshalling from JSON to POJO by JACKSON library. (it has proper id)

Comment: I setup a project doing the same thing except JSON transformation (created a new object instead) and I can't reproduce this. Please upload a minimal version of your problem somewhere.

Comment: Try implementing your own `equals` and `hashCode` (instead of Lombok's ones) and use getters for fields involved (`this.getValue()` and `other.getValue()` instead of `this.value` and `other.value`). Does it work properly then?

Answer (score -1):

You wrote : 'They are linked using an association table'

Are you shure ?

Default mapping for ManyToOne is an additonal foreign key in  the many side. In your case the table child should have an additional field 'parent_id' and there is no additional association table.
Every child can be associated exactly to one parent.

Maybe you can post the Exception of 'hibernate tries to insert already existing row into association table' ?